# Group vs Composite SWT?

Tags: java, swt

What is the difference between Group Control and Composite apart from the way they look? 
Can i place a container inside a Group? If yes, what Layout will I have to use? I tried placing a container inside a Group but the controls inside the Container did not show up.

```
Group grp= new Group(container, SWT.NONE);
grp.setText("XYZ");
grp.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
Conatiner cnt = new Container(grp, SWT.NONE);
cnt.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,true));
cnt.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, false, false));
Text text = new Text(cnt,SWT.LEFT);
```

Comment: Any feedback to my answer?

Comment: @Baz : Yes baz i am working on it :) Will let you know

Comment: Ok, good to hear. Hope it works out for you.

Comment: @Baz It worked. Thank you so much. You are like the wiki of SWT lol. Can you suggest me some good reading stuff for SWT

Comment: Well, there is [this](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html), [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/SWT/article.html) and [all that](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/eclipse.html). Happy reading :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Group` extends `Composite`. That means that both of them can have child elements. Both can be placed inside the other. Your problem seems to be caused by the fact that your `Group` doesn't have a `Layout`. It's not enough to set a `Layout` to the `Composite`.

Here is a minimal example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    Group group = new Group(shell, SWT.NONE);
    group.setText("Group");
    group.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    Composite composite = new Composite(group, SWT.NONE);
    composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, true));

    new Label(composite, SWT.NONE).setText("left");
    new Label(composite, SWT.NONE).setText("right");

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```